# Code to detect webcam does not work on Chrome when running on server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webcam, detect

I am using the Javascript code below to detect a webcam:

```
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia 
    || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
    || navigator.mozGetUserMedia 
    || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
```

It works with Chrome when the application is running on my computer. But when I am running the application on the server, it works fine with Firefox but not with Chrome. I am getting the error message "No Camera available" like if it is trying to detect the webcam on the server side (the server has no webcan) and not on the client side, my computer.
What can be the problem?

Comment: But, what is the problem? If the server has not a webcam, I don´t understand the problem.

Comment: It's really, really not clear at all where/how you run the code. Obviously, if you run the code on the server (but that would most likely be in node.js, or phantom.js or equivalent), it would tell you about what is actually available on the server, because that's where it runs. If that's not your scenario, you'll have to be more explicit.

Comment: The application is installed on the server. But I am connecting and running a session from my laptop. So, it should run in the browser and detect the webcam on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

It's because Google chrome wants https connection to enable webcam.

Webcam works on google chrome only on https connection or on localhost.

Comment: no I fix my problem a long time ago so i don't have question.

But I think I help him by giving one possible cause of his problem : he was asking why webcam only work  on localhost and not when his website is on server.

I will edit my answer to make it more understandable.

Comment: Yeah.. this can be count as one of the answers, @JonathanArgentiero just doesn't understand